# apache2.conf: Difference between Timeout and KeepAliveTimeout

Tags: apache2, apache2.2

What is the difference between the Timeout (default 300) and the KeepAliveTimeout (default 15) in the apache2.conf ? And do these values somehow depend on each other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html) docs :

**KeepAliveTimeout** : The number of seconds Apache will wait for a subsequent request before closing the connection. Once a request has been received, the timeout value specified by the **Timeout** directive applies. Setting KeepAliveTimeout to a high value may cause performance problems in heavily loaded servers. The higher the timeout, the more server processes will be kept occupied waiting on connections with idle clients

**TimeOut** : Amount of time the server will wait for certain events *before failing a request*. The TimeOut directive defines the length of time Apache will wait for I/O (e.g., when reading data from the client, when writing data to the client, etc.)